# React Components Functional

Tags: components

I have a question about React functional components, specifically about functions in functional components. For instance:

```
    function WorkshopComponent(props) { 

      function renderWorkshopElements() {
           props.elements.map((element) => {return <Element key={element.id} {...element} />})
      }

      return (<div> renderWorkshopElements() </div>) 

    }
```

My Q: Is there an argument to only use props object inside the component level function? Is it superior to write this:

```
function WorkshopComponent(props) { 

      function renderWorkshopElements(elements) {
           elements.map((element) => {return <Element key={element.id} {...element} />})
      }

      return (<div> renderWorkshopElements(props.elements) </div>) 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*I think it is a really good question and i'd like to ear other ppl opinions.*

In your first example, you embrace the power of scope, which i believe is good. I personally use arguments in function only when i don't have the value in my scope already (eg: events, elements of array, etc)

In your second example, it is interesting to notice, that you don't even need this function to be included inside the WorkshopComponent, it could be declare next to it and would work the same (rendering wise). This is great if you want to unit test this function.

**tl;dr: I'd say version 1 make more sense most of the time**